# Applying Bootstrap styles to Twitter Typeahead controls

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, twitter-typeahead

I have added a twitter typeahead control to my application which is styled with bootstrap 3. Here is a picture of the current look of the control:

[image: Unstyled Twitter Typeahead Control]

No Bootstrap styles are applied. In fact, the thing doesn't have any styling added to it. It just adds text in transparent container below the text box (the background is red to highlight this transparency).

I found no information about styling in the documentation, but the examples, [found here](http://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/examples/), look great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolution

I did a quick double check so I wouldn't get LMGTFY'd and found the following github fork with code that resolves 98% of the issues. I figured it would be reasonable to post the answer just in case. It's almost a duplicate, but all of the current issues on stackoverflow currently refer to typeahead v0.9.x.

Fix here: https://gist.github.com/jeffgabhart/6140176